# C# List<T> RemoveAt(int32) function removes all indexes for each List in a 2d List instead of specified list only

Tags: c#, .net, list, linked-list

As title states...

- I have a 2d list
- the list contains 9 other lists containing integers 1 - 9

```cs
List<List<int>> empty_cells;
List<int> row = new List<int> {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
for (int i = 0; i <=8 ; i++)
{
    empty_cells.Add(row)
}
```

- I want to remove an element from a chosen sub list

```cs
empty_cells[sublist_index].RemoveAt(index_to_remove)
```

This code instead removes the item at `index_to_remove` from **all** sub-lists in the parent list `empty_cells`. Making all Sub-lists one element shorter than before

## Two Questions

A. Why is this happening?

B. How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: You're adding the same instance each time, not copies of it.

Comment: that was fast... and makes perfect sense..... Thanks. Make an answer so I can accept it

Comment: I can overcome this by placing my new list declaration inside of the loop correct?

Comment: Depending on how you do it, yes. Jawad's solution works, using the original list as a template and cloning it using `ToList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your process to this, use of ToList()

```
List<List<int>> empty_cells;
List<int> row = new List<int> {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
for (int i = 0; i <=8 ; i++)
{
    empty_cells.Add(row.ToList());
}
```

`ToList()` method copies the values to the variable it is being set to instead of setting the reference of both variables to same data.

Comment: I accepted this because it works. However I used the solution of putting my new List<int> declaration inside of the loop. For no reason other than I have so far avoided including Linq in my project.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code doesn't compile because `empty_cells` is not assigned, so I'm assuming it's actually.

```cs
List<List<int>> empty_cells = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> row = new List<int> {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
for (int i = 0; i <=8 ; i++)
{
    empty_cells.Add(row)
}
```

There is only one `row` list created. After your code runs, every element of `empty_cells` is a reference to the same list. You can verify that:

```cs
foreach (var list in empty_cells)
{
    Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(list, row);
}
```

So doing `empty_cells[sublist_index].RemoveAt(index_to_remove);` for any indices is the same as removing the element from the original `row` list. A simple fix is to use `ToList` for each addition:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i <=8 ; i++)
{
    empty_cells.Add(row.ToList())
}
```

`ToList` creates a new `List` object with the same contents as `row`.

As a sidenote, you can write your code simpler with `Enumerable.Range`:

```cs
IEnumerable<int> row = Enumerable.Range(0, 9);
for (int i = 0; i <=8 ; i++)
{
    empty_cells.Add(row.ToList());
}
```